# PHP - Associative array is stored as regular array by foreach loop when containing only 2 values

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, associative-array

I've created a form that lets users input measured temperatures at a specific interval, let's say 0 minutes and 1 minutes. This data is sent through by an AJAX call to our server, which in turn returns a function to handle the request.

The function will retrieve the target data from the database - stored as a JSON. When the required data is found, the function will 'unpack' the JSON and alter the specific data. However, eventhough I need the user input to be stored in an associative array, somehow the input gets saved as a regular array.

The specific code that alters the data looks something like underneath:

```
        foreach($list as $list => &$items){        
            if(isset($items[$item_id])){
                
                if($temperature != ''){
                    $items[$item_id][$temp_type][(string) $minute] = (float)$temperature;
                }else{
                    unset($items[$item_id][$temp_type][(string) $minute]);
                }
            }
        }
```

The data that is sent through looks something like this:

**AJAX CALL 1**

```
$item_id = 101;
$temp_type = 'hot';
$minute = (int)0;
$temperature = (float)26.5;
```

**AJAX CALL 2**

```
$item_id = 101;
$temp_type = 'hot';
$minute = (int)1;
$temperature = (float)55.5;
```

I'm expecting the following output in my database:

```
"101":{"hot":{"0":26.5,"1":55.5},
```

However, what I receive is:

```
 "101":{"hot":[26.5,55.5],
```

**Important info:**
Whenever I send more than 2 AJAX requests to the server - i.e. when the user form contains more than 2 fields ranging between 0 - X minutes - the associative array keeps its form and everything is just fine.

So what I don't quite get at the moment, is why `$items[$item_id][$temp_type][(string) $minute] = (float)$temperature;` reverts the data back to a regular array?

Comment: did you try to cast value like this => `$items[$item_id][$temp_type][(string) $minute] `

Comment: Thanks for the comment! And that's a very smart suggestion so I just tried this, but it did not solve the problem. I'll add the casting to the question.

Comment: why do you need to have 0, 1, etc on response ?

Comment: `[26.5,55.5]` is essentially `[0 => 26.5, 1 => 55.5]`. So I don't see the real issue here. By the way, this doesn't happen when you have only two elements, this will happen any time you have *consecutive* minutes. So if your minutes are 0, 1, 2, 3 - it will be an array. If you skip one, e.g. 0, 1, 3 - it will encode an object. You're not dealing with an associative array at that level, even if you cast the numbers to strings, it's still a regular numerically indexed array.

Comment: @El_Vanja so in summary, whenever the minutes that are sent through are consecutive minutes (i.e. 0,1,2,3, ...) they'll always be seen as indexes and will be sent through as a regular array.

The reason I need an associative array, is because the amount of minutes will vary from user to user, depending on which interval they choose to measure temperature. I'm afraid that, if I end up with a regular array, I'll not be able to print out specific results based on time interval.

Comment: When you decode it, it will be the same array you've previously built to be encoded and sent as JSON. So I don't see the issue with iterating an array with consecutive keys vs. an array with inconsecutive keys. Both behave exactly the same when looped. [Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/loBeS).

Comment: As a matter of fact, here's an improved [fiddle](https://3v4l.org/7cRWL) which shows that the results can be read and processed in the same manner whether you decode as array or object. You can always iterate.

Comment: You're a legend @El_Vanja, did not think of it that way :)